# How to use conditional operator if you have to check two fields in JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to set one value or the other if one of them has undefined on null returned. Below is throwing an error if `result.details.statusDescription` returns undefined it should set `result.header.statusDesc` was my expectation.

main.js

```
const statusDescription: string = result.details.statusDescription || result.header.statusDesc || "Invalid Request";
```

Comment: Most likely `result.details` is `undefined`.

Comment: okay but it should set `result.header.statusDesc` in that case right

Comment: No, it would throw an error because you try to get `.statusDescription` of `undefined` which doesn't have any properties.

Comment: @VLAZ oh ok thanks any fix using ternary operator want to avoid if/else conditions

Comment: Optional chaining: `result.details?.statusDescription`

Comment: you can either use (result && result.details && result.details.statusDescription) or use Optional chaining (?.) - result?.details?.statusDescription